# Remove an ad from my Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

My tumblr (mixedfeels.tumblr.com) has this ad at the top of it. I'm not sure if I'm the only one that can see it, but it's really bugging me. I didn't put it there or allow ads to be there, so I'm thinking it's in the theme. If this is the case, I was wondering if there is a specific code that I can find in my theme and delete?

It would be great if you could answer this :)

Comment: I can't see any ads, so unless you have removed them it could be just you. A possible culprit is a browser extension called IWantThis - have a look at the instructions in this FAQ to see if it is there and how to remove http://iw.antthis.com/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Just so there is an answer in the appropriate place, a possible source of ads is the "IWantThis!" browser extension (which appears to act more like malware). The easiest way to check is probably to run through the uninstall instructions for your browser provided at the end of the FAQ [here](http://iw.antthis.com/faq.html).